# passing view id to onActivityResult with putExtra does not work

Tags: dynamic, view, onactivityresult

I dynamically add  views to  a LinearLayout based on field types comming from an api.

If the field type dictates 'image' i create an image selection button and add that to the view.

I also create an imageview so when onActivityResult is called i can assign the choosen image to that imageview.

However,
to find the dynamcally created imageview i need to pass some sort of identifier.

Somehow the putExtra() function does NOT pass the id.

initial vars:

```
private static final int SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE = 101;
public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "image/*";
private ImageView selectedImagePreview;
protected int tmpviewid;
```

dynamic field creation:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
TextView tmltname = new TextView(NewJobActivity.this);
tmltname.setText(vwa.getName());
ll.addView(tmltname);

Iterator it = attributes.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if(val.getType().equals("image") ) {
        Button btn = new    Button(NewJobActivity.this);
        btn.setText(R.string.select_picture);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(NewJobActivity.this);
        iv.setId(View.generateViewId());
        tmpviewid = iv.getId();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType(IMAGE_TYPE);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.putExtra("imageid",  tmpviewid);

                startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, getString(R.string.select_picture)), SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE );
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);
        ll.addView(iv);
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            int myviewid = data.getIntExtra("myviewid",-1);
            Log.i("##MYLOG###", "###imageid:" + myviewid);
            try {
                Bitmap pic =  new  UserPicture(selectedImageUri, getContentResolver()).getBitmap();
                ImageView image = (ImageView) NewJobActivity.this.findViewById(myviewid);
                image.setImageBitmap(pic);
            }
```

the image selection is working and selectedImageUri is populated but why is data.getIntExtra not retrieving the passed myviewid? (it always get the default value -1 but the tmpviewid DOES get valid id's (1,2,3 etc...))

all the accepted solutions suggest that my code should work.

maybe there is something else going on?

or perhaps I am going about the wrong way?

i noticed somewhere else that get- and setTag might be also a solution.. but i still would need to pass it around some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I got the picture ;)

You cannot pass custom extra params, well.. you can, but the called activity will not use it. When return to the caller it will send just the activity's available extras result...

If you setted up your Activity as SingleInstance in Manifest, it will not be recreated on result so you can add a public class variable "public static int referImage = 0" and set it on button click with the clicked ID. Then when you got the result you will have the image id reference on this variable.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            referImage = tmpviewid;
            ....
```

I am not sure if this solution works but the custom Extra cannot be retrieved this way.

Let me know and I will try to figure another way.

Example:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity{
   public static int referImage = 0;

   ..... Override methods ..etc

   while (it.hasNext()) {
    if(val.getType().equals("image") ) {
      final int tmpviewid = iv.getId();

      ... more code
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                referImage = tmpviewid;


}
```

When user click on Button it will set referImage = tmpviewid;

When Activity retur for Result the last value of referImage will be Button user clicked.

onActivityResult you just have to read referImage value.

Comment: how do i retrieve the referImagein in the onActivityResult?

also, the strange thing is if i change the button to a textview then the putExtra() function works without a problem.

could it be that it is not possible to use putExtra with button onclick?

Comment: You declare it right after class declaration public or private outside any method, it will be accessible in the entire class context including onActivityResult, you can just use it as a declared property :) Set before start the activity and when return the value you setted before must be there if the activity was not recreated.

Comment: but that would mean it would always set the last id. 

eg: the api returns 5 image types then 'referImage' var will hold the value 5 in the end. (each iteration will assign a new id to 'referImage' overwriting the previous value)

if someone then clicks on the second 'choose image' button i will have value 5 instead of value 2 and although someone picked an image for button 2 the image will be bound to imageview 5.

maybe i am missing the point?

Comment: Within the iteration you can declare the var as final, each Button will handle it as a constant and  onClick action you'll have a fixed value for each button.

Comment: final int tmpviewid = iv.getId(); (on iteration) and declare referImage as static int

Comment: Demonstration added on the answer above.

Comment: wow.. it... works... but i have no clue how this could possibly work.... why is the 'referImage' variable NOT overwritten each time it iterates?

Comment: great news! ;) It work because when you create a new button **"Button btn = new    Button(NewJobActivity.this);"** the Application allocate memory for this object, we are attributing the constant(final) to the referImage only when the Button is clicked, and referImage is global (for the class context) it mean that you are writing the constant tmpviewid to the memory position of this variable.

Comment: But... if you use it in a normal activity and the garbage collector destroy it, when start a new one the variable reset. You can use this technique if your activity is SingleInstance or on return of StartForResult, otherwise it is not recomended.

Comment: Ok Thx for explaining. so it works but it still seems like it's not the best way to do this sort of thing... passing values with the intent with putExtra seems like a better option but apparently you can not do it with a button. Maybe there is a much better way of passing values with intents i don't know about?

Comment: I'm not sure but when you call an activity (like gallery) via Intent, When this activity return a result, it return passing the extras determide by the activity... the activity expect receive certaind extras and will return some other but not a custom extra like myimageid for example.